# How to enable my CodeIgniter controller to correctly identify ajax calls from FullCalendar4?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, http-headers, fullcalendar-4

I am using FullCalendar 4.4.0 with a CodeIgniter application that I am working on.

In many places in my project, I am successfully using CI's `$this->input->is_ajax_request()` method to determine whether my controller is being loaded by an ajax request or not.

The problem is that when I am using [FullCalendar's single-source events option](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed) and passing a POST request, the `is_ajax_request()` call is not identifying the call as coming from ajax.

What can I do to enable my controller to correctly identify ajax calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the [major breaking changes](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3) from FullCalendar version 3 to version 4 is

> - Removal of jQuery as a dependency.

---

This is relevant because consequently:

> X-Requested-With is set only by AJAX libraries like jQuery, Mootools, Prototype etc.

- [according to @InsiteFX](https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-72688-post-361182.html#pid361182)

---

CodeIgniter's `is_ajax_request()` source code looks like this:

/ci/system/core/input.php:

> ```
> /**
>  * Is AJAX request?
>  *
>  * Test to see if a request contains the HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH header.
>  *
>  * @return    bool
>  */
> public function is_ajax_request()
> {
>   return ( ! empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest');
> }
> ```

---

This means a solution can be found a couple of ways...

1. Hack FullCalendar's /core/main.js file and add:

   Add the following line immediately after the `xhr.open()` call in the `requestJson()` method:

   ```
   xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'xmlhttprequest'); /* Food for CI's $this->input->is_ajax_request() */
   ```
2. If you are never expecting any $_POST values with a standard page load (this is true of my application), simply do not use `is_ajax_request()` for this specific task.  In your controller, just use this instead:

   ```
   if (!empty($_POST)) {
   ```

   or more simply (because the superglobal will always be declared)

   ```
   if ($_POST) {
   ```